Contradiction with the facts: if $a^2=2k$, $a=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{k}$, $a$ is not always even.
if $a^2$ is even$\Rightarrow$ $a$ is even.
$\textbf{Solution}$: proof by contradiction, suppose $a$ is odd, $a=2m+1$, $4m^2+4m+1=a^2$, $a^2$ is odd, but $a^2$ is even, therefore $a$ must be even.

But, $a^2$ is even, I can write it as :$a^2=2k, \forall k\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $a=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{k}$, which $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, and not for all $k$, $\sqrt{k}$ can be write as some number times $\sqrt 2$, it's contradict with my assumption for all k, hence not forall $a^2$ is even implies a is even.
What's the problem here?

Your $a$ has an even number of $2$s, and hence your $k$ has an odd number of $2$s. So $\sqrt{k}$ actually can push out a $\sqrt2$.

My problem is that I don't understand your argument, so I'll point out the first error I see: The fact that $a^2$ is even does not tell you that $a^2 = 2k, \forall k \in \Bbb{Z}$, it just says $a^2 = 2k, \exists k \in \Bbb{Z}$. There is no number equal to every possible value of $2k$, where $k \in \Bbb{Z}$, simultaneously.

@HackR Thank for your answer, I have considered what your are saying, but my problem at the time was that it wasn't for all the integer k.

@TheoBendit Thank you, I understand my mistake, I just consider $^2==2$
and forgot considered the square. When not discussed in real numbers, squares are not really complete.

@Young Hola has mentioned the problem in your proof. A simpler proof without contradiction is that $2$ divides $a^2\implies$ $2$ divides $a$ (since $2$ is a prime) so $a$ is even.

You want to prove that if $a$ is a positive integer and $a^2$ is even then $a$ is even.
By contradiction, suppose that $a$ is not even, so $a$ is odd. This means that there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $a=2k+1$. Then, let's compute $a^2$.
$$a^2=(2k+1)^2=4k^2+4k+1=2(2k^2+2k)+1.$$
Let $t=2k^2+2k$, which is trivially a positive integer. Then $a^2=2t+1$, where $t$  is a positive integer, which means $a^2$ is odd. This is a contradiction with the assumption that $a^2$ is even. Therefore what you claimed is completed proved.

Thanks a lot, I'm familiar with this proof, my other proof turned out to be different conclusion, but now I know where I proved wrong.

You're welcome, no problem. I'm glad for helping you :)

The correct way is to say that if $a^2$ is even then $\exists k\in\Bbb N, a\times a = 2 k$.
Now as $2$ is a divisor of the product $a \times a$, it must divide at least one of the terms of the product, so either $a$ or... $a$. Hence we must have $\exists k_1\in\Bbb N, a = 2k_1$.
BTW, this proves that $k = 2 {k_1}^2$, which explains that when you try to get $\sqrt{2k}$ you actually have $\sqrt{2 \times 2{k_1}^2} = 2k_1$ and no irrational is involved... Phew, the theory has not collapsed ;-)
